# Wordpress admin menu messed

Tags: css, wordpress

Today I have a really strange problem. My WordPress admin menu is a mess and disappears on hover. I've tried deactivating all the plugins, changing the theme, but nothing works.

Has anyone any ideas? I cannot check in "Firebug", because if I open it, my menu reloads and everything appears fine. It's the same if I refresh the page, but without change url. You can see it in the print screen.

I don't use any custom admin style or scripts.

Wordpress 4.3

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Which browser are you using? There is a known bug in chrome more info here: http://wptavern.com/a-bug-in-chrome-45-causes-wordpress-admin-menu-to-break

> The source of the problem stems from Slimming Paint which is enabled
>   by default in Chrome 45. Disabling slimming paint fixes the issue.
>
> To disable this feature, visit chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint
>   in Chrome and Enable the Disable slimming paint option, and make sure
>   the other two Enable options are disabled because they will override
>   the Disable option.

Also from the sounds of it looks like google will be fixing this as well soon

> the Chrome Development bumped up the priority of the bug and a fix is
>   likely come out before version 47
>   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179

Comment: a quick fixed also is to do a quick resize on the browser :D at least if you don't want to mess with the flags... :)

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your functions.php **to fix the bug not only in your browser but also in your client's**. I tested it and worked well.

```
function admin_menu_fix() {
    echo '<style>
    #adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_menu_fix');
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179#c37 (page found by @NooBskie)

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a rendering bug. There is a ticket open on Chrome's bug tracker about this issue, hopefully they will fix it soon.

In the meantime, here is a solution to eliminate the issue in Chrome.

- Go **chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint**
- Enable the "**Disable slimming paint**" option.
- Ensure that the "**Enable slimming paint**" option below it is not turned on.
- Then **Relaunch Chrome**.

Hope the problem will fixed.

You can also try the solution: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179#c37

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this going to be a short-lived thing, but a very weird one (especially compounded with hunting plugin breakages related to WordPress 4.3 simultaneously).

I just updated Google Chrome to the latest version and it is resolved. Before attempting any unusual fixes, I would recommend going to Chrome -> About Google Chrome first to make sure you're running the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Official Solution:

Disable slimmingPaint feature in chrome

```
1) In Chrome browser, navigate to: chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint (just enter the text into the address bar and hit enter)
2) You’ll see a list of technical options, with the “Disable slimming paint” option at the top; enable it
3) Disable the “Enable slimming paint” option if it’s enabled; just under the “Disable slimming paint” one
4) Relaunch Chrome
```

Other Solution:

If you or your clients don’t want to disable the Slimming Paint feature, then you can get around the bug by adding the following code into your theme functions.php file:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chrome_adminmenu_fix');

function chrome_adminmenu_fix() {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome' ) !== false )
        wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the settings **a little confusing at first, here's the simplification (possibly):**

1. Visit `chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint` in Chrome
2. All the slimming paint options that have `Disable` keyword in their
   hashtag/flag must be in `Enable` state
3. All the slimming paint options that have `Enable` keyword in their
   hashtag/flag must be in `Disable` state