# Styling of menu bar in Admin panel of wordpress is compromised

Tags: wordpress

While working on my project. After an unknown point of time, the admin panel in my wordpress installation has some issues.

I have noticed two of them:

**1. DISTURBED ADMIN MENU BAR:**

The css of left navigation menu bar in admin panel looks disturbed when I click on something. But adjusts fine when I reload the page. And gets cluttered again when I click on a new menu. Please see below a snapshot I have attached:

[image]

**2. DYNAMIC CONTENT ADDITION IS GONE:**

When I create a category and click on the "Add new category" button, it adds the category to the database but doesn't appear dynamically on the right panel.

[image]

And appears only after I reload my page.As you can see the category in my case "New category" appeared in the right panel only after a reload.

[image]

You can see all the images above displays an ugly menu bar.

I have faced both the issues several times on my previous projects also but could never find a solution online.

If someone has already has already gone through my problems please help me by sharing the solution and letting me know what is the way to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Have you tried turning off all third-party plugins?

Comment: Yes. But that is not the issue. I think wordpress new version has this problem. and the problem happens only in chrome. firefox is all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same for me, and it started after wp-login has stopped working. But we can't figure why.

EDIT: I've found a possible solution here, check it folks: [Wordpress admin menu messed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420917/wordpress-admin-menu-messed)

Comment: Have you ever encountered the second problem I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The solution is worked for me. Add this in your **functions.php**

```
function admin_menu_fix() {
echo '<style>
#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }
</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_menu_fix');
```

You can check the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179#c37