# Wordpress Admin Side Menu messed up

Tags: html, css, wordpress, stylesheet

Recently I noticed that Dashboard Menu Items lost the actual styles. It looks messed up now. once we click refresh it will be OK. but in page load again the same happens.[image: Wordpress Dashboard Menu Messed up] Please see the image attached.

Comment: same here, may be because of some issue with latest version update.

Comment: Have you made any code changes, plugin updates or theme updates? WordPress won't randomly start removing or messing up the admin without reason.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420917/wordpress-admin-menu-messed/32420944#32420944

Answer (score 5):

It is worked for me, just add the bellow code in your **functions.php**

```
function admin_menu_fix() {
echo '<style>
#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }
</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_menu_fix');
```

Ref: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179#c37

Answer (score 0):

It is a [known bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199) in Chrome. You can apply [this bug](https://github.com/raffjones/chrome-admin-menu-fix) to fix the problem or wait for an official fix.

The bugfix is a simple plug-in, applying a style, such that:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Chrome Admin Menu Fix
Description: Quick fix for the Chrome 45 admin menu display glitches
Author: Steve Jones for The Space Between / Samuel Wood / Otto42
Author URI: http://the--space--between.com
Version: 2.1.0
*/

function chromefix_inline_css()
{ 
    wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chromefix_inline_css');
?>
```